# How do I pass individual styles to a component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am rendering the same component several times and I want to give a different style to one of them.

Should I add className?
How do I pass a style to change the font size of this specific component?

```
   <Result
                className={Styles.reportTitle}
                question={report.question}
                text={report.resultText}
                values={[
                    {
                        percentageResult: report.overallPercentage,
                        value: report.overallPercentage,
                        resultText: report.resultText
                    }
                ]}
                color="black"
            />
```

Adding a className is what I am doing but it's not working.

Comment: You can pass style object as a props

Comment: pass className bases on index , then add appropriate styles.

Comment: I tried to pass the style object but also I'm getting nowhere. Maybe I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Into your Result Component you can set a style Attribute to do it:

```
export class Result extends React.Component {
   render () {
      return <div style={color: this.props.color}>...</div>
   }
}
```

Or you can use a [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components)

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Box = styled.div `
  color: ${color => color};
`

export class Result extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Box color={this.props.color}>...</Box>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You custom component is (probably) not propagating className to root element. Add `className={className}` there.